# Float to String: Problem with string length

Tags: ada

I would like to convert a float value to a String and created the following short example:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Example is
   A : constant Float := -1.234;
   B : constant Float := 123_456.789;
   C : constant Float := 987.654_321;

   package Float_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Num => Float);

   String_Float_A : String := "     ";
   String_Float_B : String := "          ";
   String_Float_C : String := "       ";
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Float'Image (A));
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Float'Image (B));
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Float'Image (C));

   Float_IO.Put
     (To   => String_Float_A,
      Item => A,
      Aft  => 2,
      Exp  => 0);

   Float_IO.Put
     (To   => String_Float_B,
      Item => B,
      Aft  => 2,
      Exp  => 0);

   Float_IO.Put
     (To   => String_Float_C,
      Item => C,
      Aft  => 2,
      Exp  => 0);

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (String_Float_A);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (String_Float_B);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (String_Float_C);
end Example;
```

My problem: I need to create the string variables before the call of the procedure `Put` with a sufficient length. How can this be done dynamically at runtime? Basically I need to figure out the number of digits before the dot. Then a sufficient string length would be: `1 (sign) + Number_Of_Dots + 1 (decimal separator) + Aft`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of digits before the dot of a decimal number can be computed calculating 1 plus the integer part of the common logarithm (base 10) of
the integer part of the number.

In Ada:

```
    N := Integer (Float'Floor (Log (Float'Floor (abs X), 10.0))) + 1;
```

Your program must be with'ed with Ada.Numerics.Elementary_Functions.
You must add a space for the minus sign if the number is negative.

This formula does not work if the integer part is 0, but then N is obviously 1.

Answer (score 3):

Your example uses `Float`, perhaps as a proxy for some more specific [*real type*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-6.html). If your actual data is better modeled as a [*decimal fixed point type*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-9.html), discussed [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p3-f.html#1-3), don't overlook the convenience of [*Edited Output for Decimal Types*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-F-3.html), discussed [here](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p3-f.html#2). The example below uses the string `"+Z_ZZZ_ZZ9.99"` to construct a [*picture*](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-F-3-1.html) of the desired output [`Image`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-F-3-3.html).

Console:

```
-        1.23
+  123,456.79
+      987.65
+1,000,000.00
```

Code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO.Editing; use Ada.Text_IO.Editing;

procedure Editing is

   type Number is delta 0.000_001 digits 12;
   type Numbers is array (Positive range <>) of Number;
   package Number_Output is new Decimal_Output (Number);
   Format_String : constant String  := "+Z_ZZZ_ZZ9.99";
   Format        : constant Picture := To_Picture (Format_String);
   Values        : constant Numbers :=
     (-1.234, 123_456.789, 987.654_321, Number'Last);

begin
   for Value of Values loop
      Put_Line (Number_Output.Image (Value, Format));
   end loop;
```

end Editing;

Answer (score 2):

You could make a function to do the job, something like this:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;
procedure Marcello_Float is

   function Image (Item : Float;
                   Aft : Ada.Text_IO.Field := Float'Digits - 1;
                   Exp : Ada.Text_IO.Field := 3) return String
   is
      package Float_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Float);
      Result : String (1 .. 128);
   begin
      Float_IO.Put (To   => Result,
                    Item => Item,
                    Aft  => Aft,
                    Exp  => Exp);
      return Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim (Result,
                                     Side => Ada.Strings.Both);
   end Image;

   A : constant Float := -1.234;
   B : constant Float := 123_456.789;
   C : constant Float := 987.654_321;

   A_Image : constant String := Image (A, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
   B_Image : constant String := Image (B, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
   C_Image : constant String := Image (C, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);

   use Ada.Text_IO;
begin
   Put_Line (A'Image & " => " & A_Image);
   Put_Line (B'Image & " => " & B_Image);
   Put_Line (C'Image & " => " & C_Image);
end Marcello_Float;
```

I made `Result` ridiculously long. I recognise that to calculate an exact size would in fact answer your original question; just being lazy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had the same idea using the function `Trim` but I am actually interested in determining the exact size. ;) Is a string size of 128 long enough to avoid errors/exceptions at runtime?

Comment: `Float’Last` results in 340282346638528860000000000000000000000.00. `Long_Float’Last` is about 1.8e+308, so you’d need about 315 characters. See @A.Cervetti’s answer!

Comment: Anyway there is a problem in my answer. Although correct from a mathematical point of view, there is a problem with rounding rules in Put(). That is: If the number is 9.996,  printing it with 2 digit after the decimal point, rounding away from zero put() tries to print it as 10.00, resulting in an error because the string is too short.